# break integer into elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays, integer

I need to break an integer where each digit in this integer is to be an element in an array like this:

```
$x = 123;
var_dump($x_array);
```

Will out put something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Array of digits as strings:

```
$x_array = str_split($x);
var_dump($x_array);

    0 => string '1' (length=1)
    1 => string '2' (length=1)
    2 => string '3' (length=1)
```

(2) Array of digits as integers:

```
$x_array = array_map('intval', str_split($x));
var_dump($x_array);

    0 => int 1
    1 => int 2
    2 => int 3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print_r(str_split($x));

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Don't forget the "php" tag next time!

Comment: Thanks to Graphox I got this solution:

      $x= 1234;
    $array = array();
    $x = str_split($x);
    foreach($x as $number){
     $number = intval($number);
     array_push($array,$number);
    }
    var_dump($x);
    var_dump($array);

  


but after some work and the help of Ayyash I got this:

     $x = 1234;
    $y = 1;
    $array = array();
    while($y){
    $remainder = $x % 10 ;
 
    array_push($array, $remainder);
    $x = $x - $remainder;
    $x = $x /10;
    if($x == 0){
     $y = 0;
    }  
    }