# split integer into array ( each with a var )

Tags: php

I saw this particular question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978153/break-integer-into-elements-in-an-array)

My issue is slightly different.

Lets say I have a random integer ( could be any number )

Like so: `$rank=123456`

Equally it could be `$rank=2876545672`

What I want to do is split the integer into an array dynamically, and give each value a class.

so it would grab in the example: 123456 the first number and give assign a var like `digit-<?=$num['id']`

So I could then generate something like:

```
<span class="digit-1">1</span>
<span class="digit-2">2</span>
<span class="digit-3">3</span>
<span class="digit-4">4</span>
<span class="digit-5">5</span>
<span class="digit-6">6</span>
```

Is this possible, and if so any ideas how to achieve this ? As tha bove ( spans ) would need to act dynamically so that they are created based on whatever number was generated.

Driving me nuts trying to figure it out.

Comment: Use [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).  `$vals = str_split($rank);`  :-)

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868896/how-do-i-explode-an-integer and apply your html boilerplate around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<?php

$rank = 123456;
$div = str_split($rank);

foreach ($div as $key) {
    echo '<span class="digit-', $key, '">', $key, '</span>';
} 

?>
```

I used commas instead of dots as the code loads faster.

Comment: OK, in that case don't forget the check :D

Comment: Here it is working live ( thought I would share so you could see your code in action ) http://www.422.com.au/about/growth/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $rank = 123456;
    $numbers = str_split($rank."");

    foreach($numbers as $n) {
        echo '<span class="digit-'.$n.'">'.$n.'</span>'."\n";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand you correctly but:

```
$test = 12345;
$test = (string) $test;
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($test); $i++){
    print("<span class=\"digit-{$test[$i]}\">{$test[$i]}</span>");
}
```

Comment: In this case is faster and better use foreach instead of for